# C++ Linked List Caesar Cipher Vigenere Cipher

Tags: c++, encryption, linked-list, caesar-cipher, vigenere

I am having trouble getting this code to work. I am not clear on how to use linked list to implement the Caesar cipher and the Vigenere Cipher. Any help figuring this out would be appreciated. 
The program is supposed to accept a menu choice from the user. The user will fill the list with a string of chars that create the Linked list. The cipher is supposed to compare each element in the linked list and encrypt/decrypt according to the key entered.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>

#undef NULL
const int NULL = 0;
const string ELEMENT_NAME = "whole number";
typedef int element;
const char SENTINEL = '\n';
class listnode {
        public:
                element data;
                listnode * next;
        }; 
class LList {
        private:
                listnode * head;
                listnode * tail;
        public:
                LList();
               ~LList();
                void Print();
                void InsertHead(element thing);
                void InsertTail(element thing);
                element DeleteHead();
                void ReadForward();
                void ReadBackward();
                void Clean();
                void Steal(LList & Victim);
                void Duplicate(LList & Source);
                void Reverse();
                void displayMenu();
                char userval;
                void CaesarEncryption(element CaesarKey);
                void CaesarDecryption(element CaesarKey);
                void VigenereEncryption(char VigenereKey);
                void VigenereDecryption(char VigenereKey);
                char EncryptedMessage;
                char DecryptedMessage;
 void Display();
        };
element read_element();

// Main function
int main(){
        // Declare the Ceaser key
        element CaesarKey;

        //Declare the Vigenere key
        char VigenereKey;

       // Declare menu_choice
       char menu_choice;
       LList L;
       do {
                L.Display();

                // Display the menu
                L.displayMenu();

                // Prompt the user to enter their menu selection
                cout << "Please make your menu selection: " << endl;
                cin >> menu_choice;

                // Use validation techniques to make sure the user    enters a
               //valid menu choice
                while((menu_choice != 'h')&&(menu_choice != 'c')&&
                (menu_choice != 'C')&&(menu_choice != 'v')&& (menu_choice!= 'V')&&(menu_choice != 'q')&&(menu_choice != 'm')) {
                        cout << "Error Invalid Choice. Re-enter:";
                        cin >> menu_choice;
                }
                switch(menu_choice) {
                        case 'h' :
                                L.displayMenu();
                        break;
                        case 'm' :

                               // Read the message from the user
                                L.ReadForward();
                        break;
                        case 'c':

                                // Prompt the user
                                cout << "Enter the numeric key" ;

                                // Get the user to enter the key
                                CaesarKey = read_element();

                                // encrypt using ceaser cipher
                                L.CaesarEncryption(CaesarKey);

                                //display the current message
                                cout << "The current key is " << CaesarKey;
                                cout << "." << endl;
                        break;
                        case 'C':

                                // prompt the user
                                cout << "Enter the numeric key: ";

                                // Get the user to enter the key
                                CaesarKey = read_element();

                                // decrypt using ceaser cipher
                                L.CaesarDecryption(CaesarKey);
                                cout << "The current key is " << CaesarKey;
                                cout << "." << endl;
                        break;
                        case 'v':

                                // Prompt the user
                                cout << "Enter the key: ";
                                // Get the user to enter the key
                                VigenereKey = cin.get();

                                //encrypt using vigenere cipher
                                L.VigenereEncryption(VigenereKey);

                                //display the key
                                cout << "The current key is " << VigenereKey;
                                cout << "." << endl;

                        break;
                        case 'V':

                                // Prompt the user
                                cout << "Please enter the key: ";

                                //Get the user to enter the Vigenere key
                                VigenereKey = cin.get();

                                // decrypt using vigenere cipher
                                L.VigenereDecryption(VigenereKey);

                                //display the key
                                cout << "The current key is " << VigenereKey;
                                cout << "." << endl;
                        break;
                        case 'q' :

                                // Tell the user they are exiting the program
                                cout << "You are quitting the program." ;
                        break;
                        default:
                                ;
                        break;
                }
        }while(menu_choice != 'q');
    return 0;
}

LList :: LList() {
        // PRE: NONE
        // POST: the N.O. LList is valid and empty
        head = NULL;
}

LList :: ~LList() {
          // PRE: the N.O. LList is valud
         // POST: the N.O. LList is valid and empty, and its
        //      listnodes have been deleted
        Clean();
 }

void LList :: Print() {
         // PRE: the N.O. LList is valid
         // POST: the N.O. LList is unchanged and its
        //      elements have been displayed
        listnode * temp;
        temp = head;
        while( temp != NULL) {
                cout << temp -> data << endl;
                temp = temp -> next;
        }
}

void LList :: InsertHead(element thing) {
        // PRE : the N.O. LList is valid
        // POST : the N.O. LList is unchanged, except that a
        //      new listnode containing element thing
        //      has been inserted at the head of the list
        listnode * temp;
        temp = new listnode;
        temp -> data = thing;
        temp -> next = head;
        temp -> next = head;
        if(head == NULL)
                tail = temp;
        else
                ;
        head = temp;
}

void LList :: InsertTail(element thing) {
        // PRE : the N.O. LList is valid
        // POST : the N.O. LList is unchanged, except that a
        //      new listnode containing element thing has been
        //      inserted at the tail end of the list

        listnode * temp;

        temp = new listnode;
        temp -> data = thing;
        temp -> next = NULL;
        if(head == NULL)
                head = temp;
        else
                tail -> next = temp;
        tail = temp;
}

element LList :: DeleteHead() {
        // PRE: the N.O. LList is valid and not empty
        // POST: the N.O. LList is unchanged, except that
        //      the listnode at the head end of the list has
        //      been deleted and its data element has
        //      been returned

        listnode * temp;
        element thing;

        temp = head;
        head = head -> next;
        thing = temp -> data;
        delete temp;
        return thing;
}

void LList :: ReadForward() {
        // PRE: the N.O. LList is valid
        // POST : the N.O. LList is valid, all of its
        //      previous listnodes have been deleted, and
        //      it now consists of new listnodes containing
        //      elements given by the user in foward order

        Clean();
        cout <<  "Enter the message: ";
        userval = cin.get();
        while (cin.get() != SENTINEL) {
                InsertTail(userval);
                userval = cin.get();
        }

 }

 void LList :: ReadBackward() {
        // PRE: The N.O. LList is valid
        // POST: the N.O. LList is valid, all of its
        //      previous listnodes have been deleted,
        //      and it now consists of new listnodes
        //      containg elements given by the user
        // in backwards order

        element userval;

        Clean();
        cout << "Enter the elements: ";
        userval = read_element();
        while (userval != SENTINEL) {
                InsertHead(userval);
                userval = read_element();
        }

}

void LList :: Clean() {
        // PRE: the N.O. LList is valid
        // POST:: the N.O. LList is valid and empty, and all of its
        //      listnodes have been deleted
        while( head != NULL)
                DeleteHead();
}

void LList :: Steal(LList & Victim) {
        // PRE: the N.O. and Victim LLists are valid
        // POST : the Victim LList is valid and empty the N.O. LList
        //      is valid, all of its previous listnodes have been
        //      deleted, and it now consists of the listnodes originally
        //      on the Victim LList

        Clean();
        head = Victim.head;
        tail = Victim.tail;
        Victim.head = NULL;
}

void LList :: Duplicate(LList & Source) {
        // PRE: the N.O. LList and Source LLists are valid
        // POST :: the Source LList is unchanged
        //      the N.O. LList is valid, all of its previous listnodes
        //      have been deleted, and it now consists of listnodes
        //      containing the same elements and in the same order as on
        //      the Source LList

        listnode * temp;

        temp = Source.head;
        while (temp != NULL) {
                InsertTail(temp -> data);
                temp = temp -> next;
        }
}

void LList :: Reverse() {
         // PRE: the N.O. LList is valid
         // POST: the N.O. LList is unchanged, excepts its elements are in
        //      reverse order

        listnode * temp;
        LList Helper;

        temp = head;
        while(temp != NULL) {
                Helper.InsertHead(temp -> data);
                temp = temp -> next;
        }
        Steal(Helper);
}

element read_element() {
        element userval;
        cin >> userval;
        while(!cin.good()) {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(80, '\n');
                cout << "Invalid data type, should be an element ( ";
                cout  << ELEMENT_NAME << " ), try agian. " << endl;
                cin >> userval;
        }
        return userval;
}
void LList :: displayMenu() {
        // PRE: none
        // POST: the menu is displayed for the user along with the current
        userval = ' ';
        EncryptedMessage = ' ';
        DecryptedMessage = ' ';
        cout << "------------------------------------------------------------";
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Command (h for help): h" << endl;
        cout << "m : enter a new current message from the keyboard" << endl;
        cout << "c : encrypt the current message using the Caesar Cipher";
        cout << endl;
        cout << "C : decrypt the current message using the Caesar Cipher";
        cout << endl;
        cout << "v : encrypt the current message using the Vigenere Cipher";
        cout << endl;
        cout << "V : decrypt the current message using the Vigenere Cipher";
        cout << endl;
        cout << "h : show the help menu" << endl;
        cout << "q : quit the program" << endl;
}
void LList :: CaesarEncryption(element CaesarKey) {
        //PRE:
        // POST:
        int num;
        num = userval;
        for(int x = 0;  x < num; x++){
                if(userval >= 'A' && userval <='Z') {
                    EncryptedMessage=(char)(((userval+CaesarKey-'A'+26)%26)+'A');
                }
                else if(userval >= 'a' && userval <= 'z') {
                    EncryptedMessage=(char)(((userval+CaesarKey-'a'+26)% 26)+'a');
                }
                else
                        ;
        }
        cout << "-------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout << "The encrypted message is " << EncryptedMessage << "."<<endl;
}
void LList:: CaesarDecryption(element CaesarKey) {
        //PRE:
        //POST:
        int num;
        num = userval;
        for(int x = 0; x < num; x++) {
                if(userval >= 'A' && userval <= 'Z') {
                        DecryptedMessage = (char)(((userval  - CaesarKey + 26) % 26) + 'A');
                }
                else if(userval >= 'a' && userval <= 'z') {
                        DecryptedMessage = (char)(((userval -CaesarKey + 26)% 26) + 'a');
                }
                else
                        ;
        }
        cout << "-------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout << "The decrypted message is  '"<< DecryptedMessage << "'."<<endl;
}
void LList :: VigenereEncryption(char VigenereKey) {
        //PRE:
        //POST:
        unsigned int j = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < userval; x++) {
                if(isalpha(x)) {
                EncryptedMessage += VigenereKey;
                        if(userval > 'Z')
                                EncryptedMessage += 'Z' + 'A' - 1;
                        else
                                ;
                }
                else
                        ;
        }

        cout << "-------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout << "The encrypted message is '" << EncryptedMessage << "'."<<endl;
}
void LList :: VigenereDecryption(char VigenereKey) {
        // PRE:
        //POST:
        int num;
        num = userval;
        for(int x = 0; x < num; x++) {
                if(isalpha(x))
                DecryptedMessage = (userval - VigenereKey % 26);
        }

        cout << "------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout << "The decrypted message is \"" <<DecryptedMessage << "\"."<<endl;
}

void LList :: Display() {
        //PRE
        //POST
        cout << "--------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        if(userval = ' ')
                cout << "The current message is  \"\". " << endl;
         else {
                cout << "The current message is \"" << userval << "\"." << endl;
                cout << "----------------------------------------------------";
                cout << endl;
        }
}
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: this piece of code is really too big. You should create a [mcve] so you'll get more people help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;``
int main() {
  string alphapet, plaintext, cipher;
  int option, key;
  alphapet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  cipher = "xyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw";
  cout << "choose an option atbash cioher : \n 1)to Cipher \n 2)to Decipher \n";
  cin >> option;
  cout << "enter key \n";
  cin >> key;

  cin.ignore();
  char letter;
  if (option == 1 && (key == 3)) {
    cout << "enter the plaintext to cipher :\n ";
    getline(cin, plaintext);
    for (int i = 0; i < plaintext.size(); ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 26; ++j) {
        if (plaintext[i] == alphapet[j]) {
          plaintext[i] = cipher[j];
          break;
        }
      }
    }

  }
  if (option == 2) {
    cout << "rnter the plaintext to decipher : \n";
    getline(cin, plaintext);
    for (int i = 0; i < plaintext.size(); ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
        if (plaintext[i] == cipher[j]) {
          plaintext[i] = alphapet[j];
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  cout << plaintext;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a short explanation along with your code?